# How can I spoof prop values that don't belong to android.os.Build?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, hashmap, android-ndk

With the following segment of code I'm able to spoof certain build.prop parameters such as brand, manufactuer, device, product and model:

```
data class DeviceEntries(
    val deviceName: String,
    val props: HashMap<String, String>,
    val featureLevelName: String,
    val androidVersion: AndroidVersion?,
    val lcd_density: String,
)

/**
 * List of all devices and their build props
 * GOOGLE PIXEL 6 PRO
 */
val allDevices = listOf(

    DeviceEntries("None", hashMapOf(), "None", null, ""),

    DeviceEntries(
        "PIXEL 6 PRO", hashMapOf(
            Pair("BRAND", "google"),
            Pair("MANUFACTURER", "Google"),
            Pair("DEVICE", "raven"),
            Pair("PRODUCT", "raven"),
            Pair("MODEL", "Pixel 6 Pro"),
        ),
        "Pixel 2021",
        getAndroidVersionFromLabel("S 12.0"),
        "450",
    ),
)
```

However I'm not able to spoof the value ro.sf.lcd_density
As far as I know, it doesn't belong to android.os.Build so I can't add it **or don't know how to add it** inside hashMapOf section.
I created the variable lcd_density and added the value 450 (desired density) hoping it would do the trick... but it doesn't.

Above is just a segment of the file, the full file can be found at: https://github.com/titooo7/GFN-FPS-Unlocker/blob/main/app/src/main/java/soy_titooo/xposed/gfnfpsunlocker/DeviceProps.kt

This is the first android app that I was able to fork and modify slightly to fit my purpose. Spoofing the density is the only bit that I can't get done yet

PS: I'm not using executing 'wm density' command as the purpose of the app is to spoof those props values only for certain apps and not the whole system